# How to send post data to shellinabox, or use javascript to do same

Tags: javascript, html, css, ssh, vt100

This will be a long one, so apologies in advance..

I am playing with writing a web based session manager for my team using shellinabox. Currently I have it working how I want, with each new connection, is starts a new instance of shellinaboxd on a different port(if needed).  But one thing that PuTTY Connection Manager has(what we currently use) that I can't get working, is automated logon commands.  After making a connection, we auto pass our credentials, and then any other post login commands we might use(cd /tmp, etc).

With fiddler, I can see that every key press I make sends a post the root dir. Example:

```
http://localhost:1234/?width=190&height=52&session=J793zjWa6gtKXEeV%2FeyY7g&keys=0D
```

So I thought that if I captured that session token that I might be able to test with wget or curl to send the post data to that session. Doesn't work...

My question would be, can anyone give me any pointers on what to try next?  In the end, for my POC, I want to have a button on the page(I am embedding the link above inside another page) that will allow me to press, and send key presses for a string(I can handle the string to hex conversion) straight to the console view.  I am apparently out of my depth on this one, because I have no clue what to try next.  I know that shellinabox uses vt100 for its console. I had a look at the JS for it, but couldn't find where in the js it sends keystrokes.  Also, once I open a page with the shellinabox embedded, how can I pull the current "session" token it is using?

Any help/pointers would be appreciated.